# Image resize - bad quality

Tags: java, image, scaling, image-resizing

I want to scale image from 239x210 to 22x19, I am using Thumbnailator:

```
public BufferedImage process(BufferedImage bufferedImage, CanvasData canvasData) {
    int imageSize = (canvasData.getDensity() * canvasData.getSize()) / 10;

    try {
        bufferedImage = Thumbnails.of(bufferedImage)
                .imageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
                .size(imageSize, imageSize)
                .outputQuality(1)
                .asBufferedImage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bufferedImage;
}
```

[Gimp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvI3n.jpg) ||| [Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW0Kh.jpg) ||| [Thumnailator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqGXJ.jpg)

I want to have the same output like from gimp, but I don't know how can I reach that.

Comment: Use a lossless compression like png which removes one type of problems (artifacts).

Comment: @JoopEggen but how?

Comment: `ImageIO.write`

Answer (score 1):

As Joop mentioned in the comments, the main reason for the poor image quality is because there's a lot of [compression artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact) compared to the output from GIMP.

This is because you're using the `outputQuality` method that controls the compression ratio of the output, but are not writing the thumbnail to a file, but to a `BufferedImage` via the `asBufferedImage` method.

If you take a close look at the documentation for the [`outputQuality` method](https://coobird.github.io/thumbnailator/javadoc/0.4.13/net/coobird/thumbnailator/Thumbnails.Builder.html#outputQuality(double)) you'll find it mentions that this method will not have any effect to the final image.

So, you have two options:

1. Use one of Thumbnailator's output methods that writes to a `File` or `OutputStream` so that you get JPEG stream, which honors your `outputQuality(1.0)` setting. The `toFile`, `asFile`, `toOutputStream`, `asOutputStream` methods will be your ticket for this option.
2. If you have to output to a `BufferedImage`, then you'll need to configure whatever if actually writing that `BufferedImage` to write a JPEG with a lower compression ratio -- that's happening outside of the code snippet you provided.

I'd recommend option 1, because it seems like you're communicating the intent that you want a JPEG with minimal compression to Thumbnailator, so it would make sense to let Thumbnailator write the JPEG to a file or stream.

---

*Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the [Thumbnailator](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator) library.*